# Uncaught ReferenceError: CKEDITOR is not defined

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, ckeditor

Estou usando o **CKEditor** para que o usuário possar preencher alguns textos. Na página Home do site estava dando olhando com o **DevTools** do **Chrome** e achei o erro.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: CKEDITOR is not defined - jquery.js:5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Resolvido

Como eu disse, eu usei isso na **Painel Administrativo**, e não na parte do front. Fui no **template** do front e **achei** a **chamada do arquivo .js** do CKEditor. Eu **retirei** a linha, **salvei** e dei um **F5**. **Não** deu mais mensagem de **erro**.